# C# - Return result asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, lua

I know I asked this before - but it involved threading or tasks. Now, I want to achieve the same without using threading or tasks, because I'm limited (the code is a Lua script). Now, what I want to achieve is like that:

Imagine a form with 2 buttons. The first button is called "Run", the second one is called "Set". I want Run to show a `MessageBox` with the text: `"The result was " + result`. However, I want it to show this `MessageBox` only once the result is set. So, you click the Run button, it halts the exceution of the method (the thread doesn't get stuck, though, so it's asychronous), and then when you click the Set button it sets the response to true and the code of the Run button continues and it shows the `MessageBox`.

How can I achieve this without the use of threading and tasks? Please show some examples. Moreover, if you can - show examples with threading or tasks even though my Lua code limits it. So far I've tried using a TaskCompletionSource of boolean but this involves the usage of the await operator which I can't use because it's a part of the C# sytnax (not allowed in Lua).

Best regards.

Comment: You cannot achieve more than one button click without using a background thread or an `async` method, your UI will freeze and will not let you click the second button

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But if I use an async method I'd have to use the await operator which I can't because you can't use that on Lua..

Answer (score 0):

A very primitive way would be to use the Application.DoEvents() in a loop, it continues serving your form in a very delayed way, but it works to what you specified. Ofcourse if you depend on a more complex calculation inside your run loop, you would need to call application.doevents inside the complex calculation

So, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FakeAsync test = new FakeAsync();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test.IsSet = true;
        }
    }

    public class FakeAsync
    {
        public bool Running { get; protected set; }
        public bool IsSet { get; set; }

        protected virtual void Loop()
        {
            Running = true;
            while (!IsSet)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
            Running = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (!Running)
            {
                Loop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```